# Selecting specific view in VBA im Solidworks

Tags: vba, solidworks

I have a macro that uses the following code to select a view in a SolidWorks drawing.

```
Set swDraw = swApp.ActiveDoc  
Set swView = swDraw.GetFirstView  
Set swView = swView.GetNextView
```

How do I change this to select a view named "`Drawing View1`"?

Answer (score 2):

1. Use this method:
2. Where Name = "Drawing View1"
3. Type = "DRAWINGVIEW"
4. X, Y, Z = 0 if not known
5. return type (value) is boolean

i.e.

```
Dim instance As IModelDocExtension
value = instance.SelectByID2(Name, Type, X, Y, Z, Append, Mark, Callout, SelectOption)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `swView` object is of type `iView` you can get the name using the `GetName2` method.  So you can then enumerate over each view in the drawing using the `GetNextView` method you already were, and just check if the name matches.

It's not really well documented, but for what it's worth the `GetNextView` method returns a null reference pointer (e.g. `nothing` in vb) after the end of the enumeration.

```
Set swDraw = swApp.ActiveDoc  
Set swView = swDraw.GetFirstView  
Do While Not swView is Nothing
    If swView.GetName2 = "Drawing View1" then Exit Do
    Set swView = swView.GetNextView  
Loop
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Set Part = swApp.OpenDoc6(drawpathandfile, 3, 0, "", longstatus, longwarnings)
Dim swDrawing   As Object
Set swDrawing = Part
Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
Dim myModelView As Object
Set myModelView = Part.ActiveView
myModelView.FrameLeft = 0
myModelView.FrameTop = 33
Set myModelView = Part.ActiveView
myModelView.FrameState = swWindowState_e.swWindowMaximized
swApp.ActivateDoc2 "Drawing View1", False, longstatus
Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
Set myModelView = Part.ActiveView
myModelView.FrameState = swWindowState_e.swWindowMaximized
```